# How can I use a path carry multi-params?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I hava a configure data:

```
{
    icon: 'ios-barcode',
    size: '30',
    color: '#ff9900',
    path: '/home/server_workpanel/true',
    name: 'used' + ' (' + used_count + ') ',   
  },
```

when I in `vue` file use it:

```
<router-link :to="item.path">
  <span class="icon">
    <Icon :type="item.icon" :size='item.size' :color='item.color'></Icon>
  </span>
  <div class="icon-title">
    <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
  </div>
</router-link>
```

you see, when I click the `router-link` it will skip to the path take the `path` param.

but, I want to take more params now, you see I only take a `bool` param in this time. How can I take more params in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow way for achieve pass the multi-params in path:

```
/home/server_workpanel/uid/pid
```

and in your `router.js` you should assign the params:

```
path:/home/server_workpanel/:uid/:pid
```

in your template you can get the key-value object:

```
this.$route.params
```